# Huge desktop icon font size on host machine after installing virtualbox-dkms (ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: xorg, 18.04, compiz, fonts, display-resolution

Here is a screenshot of what is happening:

[image: huge icons]

I initially thought that this was an Nvidia-related problem since I'm using an `XPS dell laptop` with two graphic cards, but running `nvidia-smi` seems to indicate that `compiz` is indeed using the nvidia graphics card (I'm using the `396` driver version if that matters). Also, notice that everything else seems to have the proper size/resolution (nautilus icons have the correct font size too). I've tried `unity-tweak-tool` but it has no effect. Note that I've changed to unity but that I have the same problem if I switch to gnome. What I find surprising is that this happened after installing `virtualbox-dkms`. What is causing this sudden change of size and how can it be fixed?